# ドラッグ&ドロップで複数ファイルをアップロードするには?

Tags: javascript, perl

[ドラッグ&ドロップされたファイルをサーバにアップロードするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41102/%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0%E3%83%89%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)
の続きです。

ご回答を得まして、ドラッグ&ドロップでファイルをアップロードすることはできました。
ただ、複数ファイルのアップロード方法が分かりません。

```
my $q = new CGI;
my @fps = $q->upload('file');
my @fnames = $q->param('file');
my $idx = 0;
foreach my $fname(@fnames){
    $fname = basename($fname);
    copy($fps[$idx], "./test/$fname");
    $idx++;
}
```

とか書いてみたのですが、一つしかアップロードされず。

なお、前提条件として、<input type = "file" multiple />を使って、ファイルダイアログで選択した複数ファイルのアップロードはできています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.dataTransfer.files は配列なので。

```
        function onDrop(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();

            var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

            for(var i= 0;i < files.length;i++)
            {
                uploadFile(files[i]);
            }

//            uploadFile(files[0]);
        }
```

Comment: できました! yyz様、いままでご親切にありがとうございました。